# Como utililizar jsonp en angular 9

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, angular9

estoy utilizando angular 9, quiero utilizar http.jsonp para obtener obtener datos datos de la api publica de themoviedb https://www.themoviedb.org/settings/api, encuentro este error en el metodo del servicio perlis.service cuando intento implementar jsonp

.. el error esta aqui, `return this.http.jsonp(urlMovieDb, {headers});`

```
  getQueryJsonP(query: string) {

    let apiKey: string='ff9b21d92f62dd60e41757c74d03d728';

    const urlMovieDb = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${query}${apiKey}&language=es&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJmZjliMjFkOTJmNjJkZDYwZTQxNzU3Yzc0ZDAzZDcyOCIsInN1YiI6IjVlNmJmYmM0MzU3YzAwMDAxMTQwYWVlZiIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.ZxnGubGV4gRNjR6wB-hwoSHyz75GnkjmIMUi8jsJFlE'
    });

    return this.http.jsonp(urlMovieDb, {headers});
  }

  getPopularesJsonP(){
    return this.getQueryJsonP('/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc?&apiKey=').pipe(map( res => res ));
  }


    ERROR in src/app/services/service-peliculas.service.ts:35:52 - error TS2554: 
Expected 2 arguments, but got return this.http.jsonp( urlMovieDb, {headers} ,'JSONP_CALLBACK');
```

He subido un ejemplo del codigo  a esta url de stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/themoviedb-http-json-p

.....................................................................................

En esta direccion url subi un ejemplo del codigo funcionando perfecto de api de themoviedb.org sin jsonp.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/themoviedb-http-json

```
getQuery(query: string) {
    let apiKey: string='ff9b21d92f62dd60e41757c74d03d728';
    const urlMovieDb = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${query}${apiKey}&language=es`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJmZjliMjFkOTJmNjJkZDYwZTQxNzU3Yzc0ZDAzZDcyOCIsInN1YiI6IjVlNmJmYmM0MzU3YzAwMDAxMTQwYWVlZiIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.ZxnGubGV4gRNjR6wB-hwoSHyz75GnkjmIMUi8jsJFlE'
    });
    return this.http.get(urlMovieDb, {headers});
  }
  getPopulares() {
    return this.getQuery('/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc?&apiKey=').pipe(map( res => res ));
  }
```

Agradezo mucho que alguien me ayude para entender como implementar jsonp, me gustaria aprender un poco mas. Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si tienes claro cómo funciona [JSONP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), pero vas a tener un problema con la autorización. En tu código tienes:

```
return this.http.jsonp( urlMovieDb, {headers};
```

Supongo que la falta de un paréntesis en una errata al copiar el código en la pregunta, así que lo ignoraremos, pero de todos modos estás intentando añadir parámetros a la consulta, cuando JSONP no los permite: **no se pueden añadir cabeceras a la petición** porque realmente no es una petición AJAX, es una simulación de la misma usando una etiqueta `<script>`. Por tanto la petición siempre será GET y no puedes añadir tu token a la misma. El error de compilación se soluciona quitando el segúndo parámetro, que no aparece en el API, y poniendo en su lugar el nombre de la función que permite obtener los datos de la respuesta

Comment: Buen dia, muchas gracias por su opinion. Efectivamente faltaba un parentesis en return this.http.jsonp(urlMovieDb, {headers}); ya lo corregi. La solucion que propones se mira buena pero no se como aplicarla, puedes por favor explicarme un poco mas. Muchas gracias @Pablo Lozano  ..aqui esta la url del servcio [https://stackblitz.com/edit/themoviedb-http-json-p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpelis.service.ts]

Answer (score 1):

como estas?
Entiendo que estas haciendo el mismo curso que yo de Angular en Udemy, me encontre con el mismo problema al momento de chocarme con el siguiente error:

> Access [service] has been blocked by CORS policy:...

Busque por todos lados un ejemplo de como usar jsonp en Angular 9, finalmente fue la misma [documentacion](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) de angular la que me ayudo bastante con esto

Como resultado llegue al siguiente codigo con el que pude hacer el get en la api de TheMovieDB

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class PeliculasService {

  private apikey = '...';
  private urlMoviedb = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPopulares(){
    const url = `${ this.urlMoviedb }/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=${ this.apikey }&language=es`;
        return this.http.jsonp(url, 'callback=JSONP_CALLBACK');
   }
}
```

Espero que sea da ayuda

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, me alegra mucho que lograste implementarlo, y gracias por compartir la forma en que lo hiciste.

Answer (score 0):

Estaba buscando la misma pregunta en Angular 11, la API de TheMovie DB ha modificado los links de sus peticiones un poco, por lo que esta es la que me funciono. El servicio devuelve una lista de Películas Populares

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeliculasService {
 private apikey = '37db1ca13ffb30d35740f27565f112a3';
 private urlMovieDb = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getPopulares(){
    const url = `${ this.urlMovieDb}/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=${this.apikey}&language=es`;
    // const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=37db1ca13ffb30d35740f27565f112a3';
    return this.http.jsonp(url, 'callback=JSONP_CALLBACK');
 }
}
```

y en el app.component.ts lo llamamos, mostrándolo por la consola

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PeliculasService } from './providers/peliculas.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'peliculasapp';
  constructor(public pelisService: PeliculasService){
    this.pelisService.getPopulares()
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Fernando. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, también puede consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)»

Comment: Esto se parece más a una pregunta. Si tienes una nueva pregunta puedes [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) acá.